# Format path with date placeholders

Tags: java, kotlin, datetime, path, formatting

Is there a way to insert date parts into a path containing date formats? I've got an application that should save files into yearly & monthly folders, but I'd rather not hardcode it.

The current naming convention is this:

> ```
> c:\reports\yyyy\MM_L_yyyy
> ```

which should result in:

> ```
> c:\reports\2024\05_May_2024
> ```

I'd like to put this template into a config file and I thought about using regex to replace each date formattable placeholder from something like this:

> ```
> c:\reports\{date:yyyy}\{date:MM_L_yyyy}
> ```

Would this be how you'd do it too or is there already a better solution for such cases?

Comment: How about writing the placeholder in the form of a `DateTimeFormatter` pattern string? Your example would be written as `'c:\reports\'yyyy'\'MM_L_yyyy`.

Comment: @Sweeper wow! That's actually pretty nice. I didn't know you could use quotes for non-date text. However, I wish it would be the other way around to make it cleaner.

Comment: I'll use the Pebble templating engine that I've just found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy with a templating engine. I picked [PebbleTemplates](https://pebbletemplates.io/). Here's an example:

```kotlin
val sourceTemplate = "c:\\reports\\{{today | date(format='yyyy')}}\\{{today | date(format='MM_MMMM_yyyy')}}"
val engine = PebbleEngine.Builder().build()
val pebbleTemplate = engine.getLiteralTemplate(sourceTemplate)
val writer: Writer = StringWriter()
pebbleTemplate.evaluate(writer, mapOf("today" to LocalDate.now()))
val result = writer.toString() // <-- c:\reports\2024\05_May_2024
```